Adding custom attributes to user in Azure AB2C sign up flow using API connector / Azure Function
I am trying to add a custom attribute to a user using the "Before creating the user" API connector in a sign up user flow. This is what I return from my function:
        var dict = new Dictionary<string, string>
        {
            { "extension_5#############################9_CustomId", id },
            { "DisplayName", "ThorDisplay" },
            { "GivenName", "ThorGiven" },
            { "Surname", "ThorSur" }
        };

        return new OkObjectResult(dict);

Doing this I end up with a user, where I can see that the display name has been set correctly:

However, trying to fetch the user data afterwards, I am not able to see my CustomId:
        var user = await _client.Users[objectId]
            .GetAsync(x => x.QueryParameters.Select = new[]
            {
                $"extension_{_extensionId}_CustomId"
            });

        return user;


But, if I do this, and then fetch the user, I am able to see the custom attribute:
var updateUser = new User
{
    AdditionalData = new Dictionary<string, object>
    {
        { $"extension_{_extensionId}_CustomId", "12345678" }
    }
};

await _client.Users[objectId].PatchAsync(user);

Any idea what I am doing wrong in my sign up flow?

Under User Attributes of the user flow, have you selected to collect the CustomId field? In order to write claims to the directory that should not be collected by the user you must select them in User Attributes, then hide that input field from the end user using custom javascript or CSS.

Thank you @bolt-io. That was my problem, I didn't think that was necessary.

As @bolt-io mentions in the comments, I did not add the attribute in User Attributes which was the issue.
